# Indexing rasters generated through algorithms into Open Data Cube database

Tags: open-data-cube

I'm getting familiar with Open Data Cube and its process to index EO data from different sources but I could not find any example of indexing products/datasets created by algorithms (i.e. running in Jupiter notebooks). Is there a proper way to do that or it is something I'm not supposed to do with ODC?

Comment: https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-config/tree/master/products some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an important question, and the short answer is that it's a really good idea, but it's not done a lot.

The normal practice for the Open Data Cube is to develop analyses in Python code in a notebook and if that analysis becomes a product, it will be re-developed a little into a data production pipeline of some description.

Two examples common in Digital Earth Australia and Digital Earth Africa are [Datacube Alchemist](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-alchemist) and [Statistician](https://github.com/opendatacube/odc-stats/).

Another alternative is to develop your own metadata that goes along with the data you're producing. I like doing this using [Rio STAC](https://github.com/developmentseed/rio-stac), just make sure to include the Projection extension.

Comment: Thank you, Alex. Indeed I intend to build prototypes through Jupiter notebooks and then move them to a more production-ready environment. Datacube Alchemist seems very close to what I was looking for and I'll have a deeper look, thanks a lot!